# Failed to create windows service Visual Studio Test Controller

Tags: visual-studio, azure, microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to configure Test controller but getting error:
I have MTM and Test controller installed on azure VM and want to setup Test controller. I have been added to Project Collection Test Service Accounts group in TFS with following permissions

[image]

## Error Log - only added relevant part of logs and made bold important ones

> BaseConfig: AddFirewallExceptionIfRequired: Firewall exception already enabled for port 6901
>   V, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.090, Found that group TeamTestAgentService exists /? True.
>   V, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.090, Found that group TeamTestControllerUsers exists /? True.
>   V, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.090, Found that group TeamTestControllerAdmins exists /? True.
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, ControllerConfiguration: Registered the url http://+:80/AgentInstallerService for user CBIS\Tokci
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, Starting service configuration...
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, Started checking the status of controller service VSTTController.
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, **Controller service VSTTController is not installed, attempting to install it now.**
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, Installing service ServicenName=VSTTController, DisplayName=Visual Studio Test Controller, Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\QTController.exe, Description=Provides Distributed Test Engine controller services, userName=tocki@some.com, Dependencies=System.String[]
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, Dependency string is dhcp
>   E, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.121, **Service failed to install. Error: 0**
>   E, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.184, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Failed to create windows service Visual Studio Test Controller. (Error Code: 0)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.InstallService(String servicePath, String serviceName, String serviceDisplayName, String serviceDescription, String username, String password, String[] rawDependencyList)
>   E, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.215, Got Exception : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Failed to create windows service Visual Studio Test Controller. (Error Code: 0)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.InstallService(String servicePath, String serviceName, String serviceDisplayName, String serviceDescription, String username, String password, String[] rawDependencyList)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.InstallControllerServiceIfRequired(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.Configure(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate ProgressUpdateCB)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ControllerConfigUI.ControllerConfigUI.ConfigureWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
>   I, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.215, Work completed for GetConfiguration() call : got out of turn error
>   E, 2017/09/02, 09:03:48.215, **Failed to create windows service Visual Studio Test Controller. (Error Code: 0)**

**Error message**
[image]

Comment: following post resolved the error but I got different error now  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c9ccf8e-a424-45ad-9a22-4c3a8246a315/setting-up-test-controllers-in-lab-environments?forum=vsmantest

Comment: What's the error now? Enable test controller log and check the detail errors: [How to enable test controller logs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aseemb/2009/11/28/how-to-enable-test-controller-logs/)